# <input type=file> not getting image

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get image file name by  tag, But when I check it through isset($_FILES['imgFile']), it returns always false.

Here is my HTML tag for getting image file:

```
<input type="file" name="imgFile" accept="image/*" id="imgFile" src=""/>
```

Here is my php code to retrieve it:

```
if(isset($_FILES['imgFile']))
{
  $img = $_FILES['imgFile']['name'];
  echo $img";
}
else
{
  echo "Image not set";
}
```

It always generate "Image not set" as an output though I have selected an image.

Comment: What is your forms enctype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the correct enctype on the form?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is required when using a file upload element.

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your form:

```
<form action="same_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imgFile" accept="image/*" id="imgFile" src=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and your php code to retrive name of the image is in the same page where the form is, then your code should be like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    if (isset($_FILES['imgFile'])) {
        $img = $_FILES['imgFile']['name'];
        echo $img;
    } else {
        echo "Image not set";
    }
}
?>
```

But if your php code is in another page, then you only need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: My php code is on same page, but it was still giving me error just because I haven't wrote enctype="multipart/form-data".